# How to safely cache my database result in memcache

Tags: go, memcached, go-gorm

I have function that returns a user.  I am using gorm for my db ORM:

```
func (dbs *DbService) GetUser(userId string) User {
  var user = &User{}
  dbs.db..Find(&user)
  return user
}
```

If I cache the result i.e. the user, will this cause memory allocation issues because I am putting the user in the cache which is a reference type, so it will cause the variable user to live beyond the scope of this function?

**Update**

So given the function above, I want to update it to be cached using [memcache](https://github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache) (below is not the actual code to store my user, just an example):

```
mc.Set(&memcache.Item{Key: "foo", Value: []byte("my value")})
```

This is an out of process cache.  I just want to know that if I store my user in this cache, it will not outlive my method call.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but if the `Find(&user)` call causes `user` to escape to the heap, then it will need to be garbage collected. We would need some valid code to determine exactly what's going on here to give a more precise answer..

Comment: The bytes you store in memcache have nothing to do with the lifetime of the value in your program. I’m not sure what your concern in, but I would write the code first to see if you even have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Memcache and Go variables (Go pointers) have nothing to do with each other.

Unless you use package `unsafe`, you (almost) never have to worry about Go variables and pointers: the garbage collector will free unreachable values, and it will never free reachable values. It's an invisible good so you don't have to think about that.

You can't store "Go variables" in memcache. You may store byte sequences (byte arrays) in memcache, but that will be independent of any Go variables. When you store a byte array in memcache, the byte sequence will be "copied".

If you want to store the *value* of a Go variable, you have to find a way to serialize the value, which may be using [JSON](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) or [gob](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) encoding, and the result byte sequence may be stored. While the encoded form sits in memcache, the Go variable may be freed (if there are no references to it).

When you need the cached value, you have to retrieve it from the memcache, and decode the byte slice (which is basically the reverse process of the serialization).